# How to mathematically write $\left| \frac{3}{\ln(\alpha)} \right| < 1$, and the procedure, to not make mistakes or confound people?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, absolute-value

I noticed that while solving this inequality, I faced a rather annoying fact: the lack of mathematical rigor in the formalism of writing things down.

$$\left| \frac{3}{\ln(\alpha)} \right| < 1$$

Now using the absolute value I get

$$\begin{cases} 
\phantom{-}\frac{3}{\ln(\alpha)} < 1 & \alpha > 1 \\\\ -\frac{3}{\ln(\alpha)} < 1 & \alpha \in (0, 1) \end{cases}$$

Now the second case is the bitter one, for if one does not pay attention he solves it wrong, indeed one might think

$$-3 < \ln(\alpha) \rightarrow \alpha > e^{-3}$$

Concluding the solution here is $\alpha \in (e^{-3}, 1)$ which is wrong because the correct one is $(0, e^{-3})$.

The fact is that when $\alpha \in (0, 1)$, we have $\ln(\alpha) < 0$. So the "real" inequality reads

$$\frac{-3}{-|{\ln(\alpha)}|} < 1$$

But this creates a redundant absolute value, which again could confuse and most of all a double minus sign, which makes to think it's exactly like the previous case.

How would one take into account the other negative sign, in order to write things properly?

Comment: start over. IF  an expression is positive, you may multiply both sides of an inequality to get a new  inequality. For you $\ln \alpha$   is not allowed to be zero,  so $| \ln \alpha | > 0$  We are permitted to multiply, giving $|3| < | \ln \alpha  | $  and $3 < | \ln \alpha  | .$  FINALLY split into $ \ln \alpha > 3$   or   $ \ln \alpha < - 3$

Comment: You know $\ln \alpha < 0$ and that multiplying by a negative reverses inequalities, so you $-\frac{3}{\ln(\alpha)} < 1$ implies $-3 > \ln(\alpha)$ and so $e^{-3} > \alpha$. I think that's pretty clear.

Comment: Since $\left\lvert\dfrac{3}{\ln \alpha}\right\rvert = \dfrac{3}{\left\lvert\ln \alpha\right\rvert}$ by the properties of absolute value regardless of the sign of $\ln \alpha$, I would rather think that in your $\dfrac{-3}{-\left\lvert\ln \alpha\right\rvert}$ the absolute sign is _not_ redundant, but the double minus signs are redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know $\ln \alpha < 0$ and that multiplying by a negative reverses inequalities, so $-\frac{3}{\ln(\alpha)} < 1$ implies $-3 > \ln(\alpha)$ and so $e^{-3} > \alpha$. I think that's pretty clear.